# PHP Pagination with SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am trying to paginate my products by using php and sql server 2008. I followed this video tutorial to help me understand how pagination works:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature...&v=K8xYGnEOXYc

The only problem is that this tutorial is about MySQL and not SQL Server 2008

Here is my code that I have written so far:

```
$tsql = "SELECT * 
        FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue 
        ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID 
        WHERE category1 = '1' 
        ORDER BY productID ASC"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql); 
$nr = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt); // Get total of Num rows from the database query 
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present 
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new) 
} else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1 
    $pn = 1; 
} 
//This is where we set how many database items to show on each page 
$itemsPerPage = 10; 
// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set 
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage); 
// Be sure URL variable $pn(page number) is no lower than page 1 and no higher than $lastpage 
if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1 
    $pn = 1; // force it to be 1 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage 
    $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value 
} 

// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons 
// This section is explained well in the video that accompanies this script 
$centerPages = ""; 
$sub1 = $pn - 1; 
$sub2 = $pn - 2; 
$add1 = $pn + 1; 
$add2 = $pn + 2; 
if ($pn == 1) { 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) { 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;'; 
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) { 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) { 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;'; 
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;'; 
} 

// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query 
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

// Now we are going to run the same query as above but this time add $limit onto the end of the SQL syntax 
// $sql2 is what we will use to fuel our while loop statement below 
$tsql2 = "SELECT * 
        FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue 
        ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID 
        WHERE category1 = '1' 
        ORDER BY productID ASC $limit"; 

$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql2); 

$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable 
// This code runs only if the last page variable is not equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display 
if ($lastPage != "1"){ 
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages 
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; '; 
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button 
    if ($pn != 1) { 
        $previous = $pn - 1; 
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> '; 
    } 
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links 
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>'; 
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button 
    if ($pn != $lastPage) { 
        $nextPage = $pn + 1; 
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> '; 
    } 
} 

// Build the Output Section Here 
$outputList = ''; 
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2)){ 
         $id = $row["productID"]; 
         $product_name = $row["product_name"]; 
         $product_price = $row["product_price"]; 
         $outputList .= '<h1>' . $product_name . '</h1><h2>' . $product_price . ' </h2><hr />'; 
} 
?>
```

As you can see right above my second query I set the LIMIT range and try to insert the $limit variable into the SELECT query. Unfortunately that doesn't work with SQL Server.

So this is the code that I don't know how to convert to SQL Server properly:

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 
$tsql2 = "SELECT * 
        FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue 
        ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID 
        WHERE category1 = '1' 
        ORDER BY productID ASC $limit"; 

$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql2);
```

I tried converting it into the format SQL Server should understand but as I'm very new to PHP and to programming in general, I was not able to get it to work

```
$limit = ($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage; 
$next_page = $itemsPerPage; 
$tsql2 = "SELECT TOP $next_page productID, product_name, product_price 
        FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue 
        ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID 
        WHERE category1 = '1' AND productID NOT IN(SELECT TOP $limit productID FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue 
        ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID 
        WHERE category1 = '1' 
        ORDER BY productID ASC)"; 
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql2);
```

Looking forward to your reply

Thank you

Comment: why do you want to convert the SQL code ? Is it not working ? Do you get a specific error message ?

Comment: It doesn't work because SQL Server 2008 does not support the LIMIT function. And I know there must be a way around this problem but I just don't have enough programming experience to get it to work. I get a warning "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean" and I know it's related to this LIMIT thing

Comment: So this post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server

Comment: I tried RowNum query explained there but I was not able to get it to work with my script. The query that is shown there is different to my script. How do I get this line of code: "$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; " to convert to SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution we use generally to solve this problem:

```
/**
 * Constructs a offsetted query.
 *
 * Because of the major differences between MySQL (LIMIT) and 
 * SQL Server's cursor approach to offsetting queries, this method
 * allows an abstraction of this process at application level.
 *
 * @param int    $offset the offset point of the query
 * @param int    $limit  the limit of the query
 * @param string $select the fields we're selecting
 * @param string $tables the tables we're selecting from
 * @param string $order  the order by clause of the query
 * @param string $where  the conditions of the query
 *
 * @return string
 */
function offset($offset, $limit, $select, $tables, $order, $where='')
{
    $ret .= 'SELECT [outer].* FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' . $order .') as ROW_NUMBER,
            ' . $select . '
            FROM ' . $tables . ($where ? ' WHERE ' . $where : '')
        .') AS [outer]
            WHERE [outer].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN '
        . (intval($offset)+1).' AND '.intval($offset+$limit)
        . ' ORDER BY [outer].[ROW_NUMBER]';

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've never used php functions before, how can I apply this function to my particular script?

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not any good experience in PHP. But I've pagination experience in MS SQL Server with ASP.Net. I think it will be better you will create an Stored Procedure that will do all pagination works in a single SP and fetch the result set in PHP. Here is the SP that can help you:

```
USE [your_db]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_product_paginate]
@page_number INT, @page_size INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY productID ASC) row_num,productId,productName
    INTO #temp
    FROM products INNER JOIN product_catalogue ON products.catalogueID = product_catalogue.catalogueID
    WHERE category1 = '1';

    SELECT productId,productName, 
    @page_size AS page_size,(SELECT Min(row_num) FROM #temp)AS first_row, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) AS tot_row
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE row_num > (@page_number - 1) * @page_size and row_num <= @page_number * @page_size;   
END
```