# SQL Server TSQL equivalent to 'MySQL Limit'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

**I know MySQL has limit command, but I don't know what command should I use in SQL server 2008?**

I need select clientId and last day of each pickup, most of the clients have multiple pickups (65 000 + records in pickup table).

```
select  P.ClientID,LastName+' '+FirsName as Name , Adress,p.PickupDate
from Pickup P,Clients C
where P.ClientID= C.ClientID
order by PickupDate desc limit 1


throwing error *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.*
because **LIMIT** is not key word in SQL server
```

Comment: i know that's why i am asking

Comment: This was already answered here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the limit command is top in sql server

```
select top 1 P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirsName as Name 
   ,Adress
   ,p.PickupDate
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
order by PickupDate desc
```

per poster's clarification - this isn't even a top/limit question. this is a simple group by statement.

```
select P.ClientID
   ,LastName+' '+FirsName as Name 
   ,Adress
   ,max(p.PickupDate)
from Pickup P
join Clients C on P.ClientID= C.ClientID
group by p.clientid, lastname + ' ' + firsname,adress
```

Comment: it is not right  because its return only last record but i need return last record for each clientID in table

Comment: lol - this is what you specified in requirement above. it can be modified for what you intended (which i'll edit into answer).

Comment: no way! it was that simple? really? i spend almost day to do it. and it  just simple join with MAX function. Thank YOU !! @mson

Comment: i think it's funny that 4 dudes didn't even read the problem and tried to close your question down.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done (pre-2012) using [windowing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
;WITH Data
AS
    (
    SELECT P.ClientID
        , LastName + ' ' + FirsName as Name
        , Address
        , PickupDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.ClientID ORDER BY PickupDate DESC)
            AS [Entry #]
    FROM Pickup P
    JOIN Clients C
        ON P.ClientID= C.ClientID
    )
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE [Entry #] = 1
ORDER BY PickupDate DESC
```

See [this blog post](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/04/26/offset-without-offset.aspx) for some good enhancements to the technique (to avoid scanning unnecessary rows).

Comment: Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov - apologies, forgot the CTE.

Comment: Thanx it works ! but where I can find something which can helps me understand your query? as I sad it works but I want to know how :)

Comment: Is there a way to make it simpler? because I need wright procedure based on this query which will change ststusId of client if he/she did not do pickup more than 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select P.ClientID, LastName+' '+FirsName as 'Name', Adress, max(p.PickupDate)
from Pickup P,Clients C
where P.ClientID= C.ClientID
GROUP BY P.ClientID, Adress, LastName+' '+FirsName
order by PickupDate desc
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b04f/1)

Comment: I need only last PickupDate for each ClientD,your query will list all of the records for each clientID. It is my original query but without limit 1 :)

Comment: Check the edit..  Hope it helps