# sql syntax error for select statement

Tags: sql-server-2012

It's first time to work on sql server. i am getting error at "END" as "incorrect syntax  near END". suppose if i remove "limit 20", its not sowing error. how can i fix it. 
my proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GettotalApps]
AS 
BEGIN
   SET  XACT_ABORT  ON
   SET  NOCOUNT  ON

   SELECT
       v.appId,
       v.Description,
       (SELECT COUNT(appidorchannelid) 
        FROM ratings r 
        WHERE r.AppIdOrChannelId = v.channelid) AS Channelvotes
   FROM 
       apps v
   WHERE 
       v.ChannelStatusId = 1 
       AND v.IsChannelPrivate = 0
   ORDER BY 
       SubscriberCount DESC 
   limit 20
END
```

Comment: read answer on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a `LIMIT` keyword - that's a MySQL specific, non-ISO/ANSI-standard extension.

Use the `TOP` keyword instead:

```
 SELECT TOP (20)
       v.appId,
       v.Description,
       (SELECT COUNT(appidorchannelid) 
        FROM ratings r 
        WHERE r.AppIdOrChannelId = v.channelid) AS Channelvotes
 FROM 
      apps v
```