# Select a subset of data on three large databases

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I am trying to read from 3 separate databases using dynamic user defined criteria (Every query will be different).  Then to display the result of that query (100,000+ rows) on a website.  Everything currently works, but the queries can take over a minute.

So far my best solution is to use Data Virtualization or Paging, where I could use just an Ajax Call to Query Server for the next page, or next 100 rows. I am pretty new to SQL, so I don't know how to make that query.

On the server side:

```
    SELECT <ATTRIBUTES> FROM DB1, DB2, DB3 WHERE ROW_NUM > lowerLimit 
    AND ROW_NUM < upperLimit
```

However this doesn't work because as far as I can tell there isn't a ROW_NUM variable in SQL server.

On the client I just want to do something along the lines of this where I would just get the next 100 rows.

```
    $("#nextPage").click(function () {
        //get the string from the textbox
        start += 100;
        end += 100;
        loadFromDataBase(start, end);
    });
```

I thank you in advance, and please let me know if you have any better ideas.  I am pretty new :)

Comment: Apply a [limit/offset in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server#answer-9013516)

Comment: Thanks I will look into this.  It looks very promising

Answer (score 0):

We were able to use paging by doing:

```
SELECT TOP N <ATTRIBUTES> FROM DB1, DB2, DB3 ORDER BY Field
```

Where N is the page size the end user chooses and Field can also be chosen, but has a default.
Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess I am a little confused about how you would get a particular range of values. For example if N = 100, it would return the first 100 results.  But then how would I get the next 100 results ? Sorry I'm new I might just be missing something obvious.  Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the link Nate Whittaker posted under your question - that is a more robust explanation.