# How to get the fourth highest value using sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have student table which has column of score. I want to get the fourth highest score,Where the table data is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT score FROM table ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

So you would write:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name
LIMIT 3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT score
FROM student
ORDER BY score asc
LIMIT 3, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server queries one can use folowing statmenet:

```
with data as 
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as rownum,
        id
    from thetable 
)
select * from data 
where rownum = 4 
order by id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL doesnt support `LIMIT` .You have to do it using `TOP` Keyword or by `ROW_NUMBER()`
for your reference here is the link [LIMIT IN MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server)

You can do it by using ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC) AS RowNumber,
      *
      FROM student
 ) AS foo
WHERE RowNumber = 4
```

You will get 4th highest score

or you can do it like this also

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC) AS RowNumber,
      *
      FROM student
 ) AS foo
WHERE RowNumber >3 and <=4
```