# Is there an equivalent MYSQL "LIMIT" Clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, limit

My pagination code in MySQL returns the query with a `LIMIT` (`SELECT * FROM tableTest LIMIT $start, $display`) to display the current rows.

Is there a way to have this logic in SQL Server?

Comment: I think this topic explain all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MSSQL` you need to use [`FETCH-OFFSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

```
<offset_fetch> ::=
{ 
    OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS }
    [
      FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY
    ]
}
```

From MSDN

> OFFSET { integer_constant | offset_row_count_expression } { ROW | ROWS
>   } Specifies the number of rows to skip before it starts to return rows
>   from the query expression. The value can be an integer constant or
>   expression that is greater than or equal to zero.
>
> FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } { integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression
>   } { ROW | ROWS } ONLY Specifies the number of rows to return after the
>   OFFSET clause has been processed. The value can be an integer constant
>   or expression that is greater than or equal to one.

Comment: You should mention that `offset fetch` does not work for versions before 2012.