# PHP PDO SELECT LIMIT issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been troubleshooting for hours and I keep either getting this error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

or not getting a return at all with the following code(this is the simplified version I've been troubleshooting with anyway):

```
 $userName = "currentUser";

    // getting data
    $amper = "";
    $data = "";
    $limit = 10;

    // here you go:
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE playerName <> :userName ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :limit";
        $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':userName ', $userName );
        $stm->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    try {
        $stm->execute();    
        $results = $stm->fetchAll();
        foreach ($results as $row) {            
            $data .= $amper."userDataOne=".$row['rowName'];
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

        print($data);
```

With the follow attribute, I receive the syntax error I listed above:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And with this attribute setting there are no errors, but no rows are selected

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

If I remove the LIMIT from the SELECT then everything works with either setting, so I need some help figuring out what's going on.

Comment: I've also tried use "... LIMIT 10"; and that gives me the same syntax error.

Comment: The only new syntax change from that thread was using intval() to identify it as an integer, unfortunately it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013177/mysql-limit-clause-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message you are using Microsoft SQL Server.  SQL Server doesn't use LIMIT, instead you need to use [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) at the front of the query, e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name
```

Comment: That is certainly a very helpful piece of previously unknown advice.  Thanks for that.  Now I just need to add in some more demo rows to make sure the RAND() is working.

Comment: In case anyone else has this particular issue in the future, the MS Azure version of RAND is NEWID.