# SQL Duplicate result messages

Tags: sql, chat, message

I have SQL query:

**Here is code which I actually using:**

```
SELECT m.message_id, m.message_subject, m.message_message, m.message_smileys, m.message_datestamp, u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_avatar
            FROM ".DB_MESSAGES." m
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT user_id, user_name, user_avatar 
                    FROM ".DB_USERS." 
                ) u ON m.message_from=u.user_id

            WHERE message_folder='0' AND ((message_to='".$userdata['user_id']."' AND message_from='2')
            OR (message_to='2' AND message_from='".$userdata['user_id']."'))
            ORDER BY message_datestamp
```

Result:

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Ev5.png)

What I need:

[Needed Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7hNb.png)

Database: prntscr.com/9vm1s4

Example: 
**me:** Hello 12:10 AM 
**he:** Hi 12:20AM
**he:** Have are you ? 12:22AM
**me:** Fine 1:10PM

Any advice?

Well thank you

Comment: This should answer your question (possible duplicate):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128043/limit-results-on-sql-request

Comment: A more informative reply would, well, provide more information. Help us help you.

Comment: DB: [link](http://prntscr.com/9vm1s4) I'ts simple chat based on PHP Fusion. I need show mesages from me to him and from him to me ordered by time. Example: **me:** Hello 12:10 AM, **he:** Hi 12:20AM, **he:** Have are you ? 12:22AM, **me:** Fine 1:10PM

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is getting down-voted because it doesn't include enough useful detail. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and, regarding images,  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `GROUP BY  m.message_from` before the `ORDER BY` part

Comment: That would result in an error, since the select list includes other columns.   At least, it would in SQL Server.

Comment: Now I get only 2 resaults ... but I need all from DB

Comment: OP can easily solve this by adding the column to the `select`

Comment: @MarekBrutusGajdoš in the "needed" image there is only 2, explain more what you need please

Comment: When I making "needed" image. I removed duplicated messages with inspector. 
In my DB is many messages and all of message have sender ID and reciver ID
Its my full resault: [link](http://prntscr.com/9vlxqs)

Comment: So you want all messages of a user to be returned but grouped together?

Comment: If that's the case then add to `ORDER BY` the `m.message_from`, this way all messages for user X will be returned after each other THEN all messages for user Y, etc ...

Comment: DB: [link](http://prntscr.com/9vm1s4) I'ts simple chat based on PHP Fusion. I need show mesages from me to him and from him to me ordered by time

Answer (score 0):

PHP Fusion add message to DB duplicated.

Here is the code which I am actually using:

```
SELECT m.message_id, m.message_subject, m.message_message, m.message_smileys, m.message_datestamp, u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_avatar
            FROM ".DB_MESSAGES." m
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT user_id, user_name, user_avatar 
                    FROM ".DB_USERS." 
                ) u ON m.message_from=u.user_id

            WHERE message_folder='0' AND ((message_to='".$userdata['user_id']."' AND message_from='2')
            OR (message_to='2' AND message_from='".$userdata['user_id']."'))
            ORDER BY message_datestamp
```